# Rename "Algorithm" to "Listing"

Tags: floats, listings, lyx, algorithms, naming

### Background

Syntax-highlighted [source code](https://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image) image listings are being used as Algorithm floats with the `lst:` prefix for captions.

### Problem

The following LaTeX code in the preamble renames the caption for the Algorithm float to Listing, as desired:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatname{algorithm}{Listing}
```

However, the cross-reference label using the following command remains "Algorithm" (should be "Listing"):

```
\ref{lst:Internationalization-Look-up-Method}
```

Essentially, I am trying to rename Algorithm floats to Listing floats. (The book will have no algorithms.) LyX has `Algorithm`, `Figure`, and `Table` as floats to insert. If there was a way to configure and add `Listing` to the same menu (**Insert >> Float >> Listing**), that would also be a great solution.

### Ideas

The following failed:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}
```

The following eliminated the word "Algorithm" for the reference label altogether:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Listing}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Listings}
\def\lstlistingautorefname{Listing}
```

I have not yet looked into the `babel` package.

### Question

How can you rename "Algorithm" to "Listing" everywhere, including:

- Caption
- Label reference
- In the front matter (i.e., List of Listings rather than List of Algorithms)

### Related

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814714/latex-how-to-change-title-in-listings
- http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg67681.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Do not mix `lst:` with Algorithm floats. The previous solution used `\newcommand{\algorithmname}{Listing}`, but this could result in *LaTeX Error: Command \algorithmname already defined*. Instead, apply the following changes:

1. Rename `lst:` to `alg:`.
2. Change the preamble to:

   ```
   \usepackage{float}
   \floatname{algorithm}{Listing}
   \renewcommand{\algorithmname}{Listing}
   ```

This does not change the "List of Algorithms" to "List of Listings". The text is found in "stdfloats.inc":

```
Float
    Type                  algorithm
    GuiName               Algorithm
    Placement             tbp
    Extension             loa
    NumberWithin          none
    Style                 ruled
    ListName              "List of Algorithms"
    LaTeXBuiltin          false
End
```

The improper way to fix this is:

1. Edit stdfloats.inc.
2. Change "List of Algorithms" to "List of Listings".
3. Click **Tools >> Reconfigure**.
4. Restart LyX.

At this point, "List of Algorithms" will read "List of Listings".

Answer (score 4):

Fora separate doc add in `Document > Settings > Local Layout`:

```
Float
    Type                  listing
    GuiName               Code Listing
    Placement             tbp
    Extension             lol
    NumberWithin          none
    Style                 ruled
    ListName              "List of Listings"
    LaTeXBuiltin          false
End
```

Then you can insert this with menu `Insert > Float > Listing`.
This makes the choice document-specific and allows you to use both, rather than change the entire Lyx install.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `List of Algorithms` to `List of Listings` with:

```
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{ 
  \begingroup 
    \listof{algorithm}{List of Listings} 
  \endgroup 
}
```