# Renaming Algorithm to Heuristic in algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithms, naming, algorithm2e

I am trying to write some heuristics for a problem using the `algorithm2e` package.

However as you may know, when you write :

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Heuristic 1: Name of Heuristic}
 ...
\end{algorithm}
```

The output says

---

**Algorithm 1**: Heuristic 1: Name of Heuristic

---

Do someone know how do I get it to write:

---

**Heuristic 1**: Name of Heuristic

---

instead ?

PS. I don't know if this command does the trick: `\SetAlgoRefName{}` I could not get it to work, anyone has an example where they used it?

Related topics are:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg67681.html

In different packages:

- [Rename "Algorithm" to "Listing"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6288/rename-algorithm-to-listing)
- [Customizing the algorithm/algpseudocode package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18402/customizing-the-algorithm-algpseudocode-package)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\SetAlgorithmName` requires three arguments:

```
\SetAlgorithmName{algorithmname}{algorithmautorefname}{list of algorithms name}
```

such as

```
\SetAlgorithmName{Heuristic}{heuristic}{List of Heuristics}
```

You could also directly redefine the macros of the `algorithm2e` package:

```
\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Heuristics}
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{Heuristic}
\renewcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{heuristic}
```

Comment: Hurray! Actually I did not have the right version of algorithm2e at the office. That was why it did not work. Please accept my apologies for making you waste your time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! But when I try to search the keywork `listalgorithmcfname`, `algorithmcfname ` and `algorithmautorefname ` for a deeper understanding, I can't get any satisfying references, even in the [algorithm2e.sty manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf). Could you point out any good explanation references for these keywords?

Comment: Why are there still numbers

Comment: How did you discover this?  I search the docs but no luck.

Comment: @caveman It's nearly 10 years ago, but I guess I looked into the source code.