# Translate the caption label "algorithm" in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, naming, algorithm2e

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming Algorithm to Heuristic in algorithm2e package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22477/renaming-algorithm-to-heuristic-in-algorithm2e-package)

i want to get the caption label "algorithm" translated into my language, so that the caption is like:

```
Algorithmus 1: Blablablabla bla
```

and not like:

```
Algorithm 1: Blablablabla bla
```

The code is like:

```
\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Blas in der heutigen Bla}
\label{blabus}
\end{algorithm}
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I used: 

    \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algorithmus}