# How to change listing caption?

Tags: listings, captions, algorithms, pseudocode

I have some listings that contain pseudo-code of algorithms. And I use this:
`\lstset{caption={Descriptive Caption Text},label=DescriptiveLabel}`
to add captions to them.

My problem is that the caption at the created file shows
`Listing 1: Descriptive Caption Text`. I would like it to write
something like `Algorithm 1: Descriptive Caption Text`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Related: [Rename “Algorithm” to “Listing”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6288/5764)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The following modifications are what you're after:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}% Listing -> Algorithm
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Algorithms
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Descriptive Caption Text},label=DescriptiveLabel]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
Write('Case insensitive ');
WritE('Pascal keywords.');
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}​
```

The example was taken directly from the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: Can we remove semicolon right after `Algorithm 1`?

Comment: @alper" I see you [asked a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670476/5764). Good! I provided [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670479/5764).

Comment: Great! In case this is useful for anyone else, note that this won't update the label used by \cref{} (i.e., when using cleveref), which can be done like so:
\crefname{listing}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}
\Crefname{listing}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the lstlistings name in between for one listing and rename it back. Just renewcommand multiple times e.g.,

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code} % Listing->Code
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Example of Code}
B0:
    b = m
    c = n
    if p is true then goto B1 else goto B2
B1:
    a0 = b
    goto B3
B2:
    a1 = b
    goto B3
\end{lstlisting}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}. % Code to Algorithm
```